# How to redirect to a page in nginx with custom query params in odoo server?

Tags: nginx, redirect, dns, odoo, nginx-config

I have an odoo instance hosted on my cloud server and it can be accessed through **https://odoodomain.net**. What I want to do is that I have a page which can be accessed through **https://odoodomain.net/jobs**. I want to access that page from a new domain like **https://odoojobs.net**. That page can also have query params. Suppose that when a browser requests **https://odoojobs.net/1?order=date**, it should be redirected to **https://odoodomain.net/jobs/1?order=date**. How can I achieve that? Please refer the following nginx configuration.

```
# Odoo Upstreams
upstream odooserver {
 server 127.0.0.1:8011;
}

# http to https redirection
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name odoodomain.net.net 111.111.111.111:8011;
    return 301 https://odoodomain.net$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name odoodomain.net;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo_error.log;

   # SSL
    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl_wildcard/nginx_cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl_wildcard/odoodomain.net.key;

    # Proxy settings
    proxy_read_timeout 720s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
    proxy_send_timeout 720s;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host odoodomain.net;

    # Request for root domain
    location / {
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://odooserver;
    }

    # Cache static files
    location ~* /web/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
        proxy_buffering on;
        expires 864000;
        proxy_pass http://odooserver;
    }

    # Gzip Compression
    gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
    gzip on;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be handled on a lower level, using controller.py in a custom module, for example

to redirect  https://thanatosophia.com/overcoming_grief

to https://en.thanatosophia.com/overcoming_grief:

```py
@http.route(['/overcoming_grief', ], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def thanato_urls_redirect_en1(self, page=1, **searches):
    if request.website.name == "Thanatosophia":
        return werkzeug.utils.redirect('https://en.thanatosophia.com/overcoming_grief', 301)
```

Answer (score 0):

edit nginx config like this

```
location = /{
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://upstream_xxx/$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the directive proxy_set_header:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://odooserver;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    # ...
}
```